# QML window is bouncing while changing size and position

Tags: qt, qml, window

My purpose is to glue the window to the right alignment of the screen while resizing.
During animation (or changing explicity) of window width and x (binded to width), `ApplicationWindow` is bouncing to left (flickering for changing explicity).

[image: QML window bouncing/flickering]

I've already was searching for the solution, but nothing is working for me.
Adding the attribute:

```
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES);
```

helped a lot, but window is still bouncing to left and right.

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    height: 300
    width: 300
    visible: true
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    x: Screen.width - width

    Material.theme: Material.Dark
    
    NumberAnimation on width {
        id: animation
        easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
    }

    property var lowerSize: true

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        
        Button { 
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            
            enabled: !animation.running
            text: lowerSize ? 'Size up' : 'Size down'
            onClicked: { 
                animation.from = lowerSize ? 300 : 600
                animation.to = lowerSize ? 600 : 300
                animation.start()
                lowerSize = !lowerSize
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've made example code for reproducing the issuee on github [qml-flickering-example](https://github.com/piwaneczko/qml-flickering-example).

Answer (score 0):

I had slightly different behavior on macOS than you are seeing in Windows (stutters on shrink for me) but it does indeed still stutter.

It appears to be because you are animating the width but then relying on QML bindings to update x. As a result, the x update is lagging behind the width update by one frame.

Using a ParallelAnimation and animating both at the same time fixed it for me:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    height: 300
    width: 300
    visible: true
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint

    Component.onCompleted: {
        x = Screen.width - width;
        y = 0;
    }

    Material.theme: Material.Dark

    ParallelAnimation {
        id: animation

        NumberAnimation {
            id: widthAnimation
            target: root
            property: "width"
            easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
        }
        NumberAnimation {
            id: xAnimation
            target: root
            property: "x"
            easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
        }
    }

    property bool lowerSize: true

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        
        Button { 
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            
            enabled: !animation.running
            text: lowerSize ? 'Size up' : 'Size down'
            onClicked: { 
                widthAnimation.from = lowerSize ? 300 : 600
                widthAnimation.to = lowerSize ? 600 : 300

                xAnimation.from = lowerSize ? Screen.width - 300 : Screen.width - 600
                xAnimation.to = lowerSize ? Screen.width - 600 : Screen.width - 300

                animation.start()
                lowerSize = !lowerSize
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't help for me. Same behavior on Windows 10

Comment: My only guess is that the Window manager is delaying the window repositioning in relation to the resize for some reason (regardless of them both being set at the same time). It could be that Windows is animating the x or width change which conflicts with your animations. Have you tried just changing the x or width without animation and seeing if Windows is performing its own animation of that change?

Comment: BTW, I noticed your CMake setup was not properly recompiling the QML on each run. You might want to try a clean/rebuild and see if that is indeed a problem.

Comment: Yes I tried to change only x and width, and it look good.  Problem occurs only in parallel animation.0
QML files are not added to qml.qrc for compilation consciously for faster implementing. After compiling the cpp sources, I'm runnig exe from working_dir=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} and qml files are reloaded after startup without need of recompilation